# Bash add newline if missing

Tags: bash

I have difficulties in understanding the following code:

```
    lastline=$(tail -n 1 $bc; echo x); lastline=${lastline%x}
    if [ "${lastline: -1}" != $'\n' ]; then
        echo >> $bc
    fi
```

I suppose it's all about adding a `\n` in the file `$bc` if the last line is not already one. However `echo x` and `lastline%x` and `${lastline: -1}` does not make sense to me at all. What am I missing?

The file `$bc` contains only lines like:

```
Sample1,ATAGFAT
```

Comment: See [bash parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion).

Comment: Note that real men [do the same with a single sed statement](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically a check if your file `$bc` is not ending with newline then add a newline in it.

- `tail -n 1 $bc; echo x` - Prints last line of file `$bc` and then prints literal `x`
- `${lastline%x)` - removes `x` from your file data `$lastline`
- `"${lastline: -1}"` - reads last character from variable `$lastline`
- `"${lastline: -1}" != $'\n'` - compares last character with newline character
- `echo >> $bc` adds a newline if above check fails

Comment: The `echo x`/`${lastline%x)` pair work around the fact that command substitution/etc. in bash/sh strip trailing newlines/whitespace. Without that you would never see a trailing newline caught by this check even if a newline existed.